# Array find all dates before current date

Tags: c#, arrays, datetime

Hello I am currently trying to array.find all the dates before the current date. I have tried both using the datetime.now as well as creating a seperate variable for current date in my struct but i keep getting "Cannot implicitly convert type 'Assignment_3.Program.Hire' to 'System.DateTime". I'm sure the solution is quite simple but as a novice it does escape from me. If you need any more of the code I will be happy to provide

```
 struct Hire
    {
        public int CustomerNo;
        public int DVDNo;
        public DateTime HireDate;
        public int NoNights;
        public DateTime CurrentDate = DateTime.Now;
    }


 DateTime result = Array.Find(hiredetails, Hire => Hire.HireDate <= Hire.CurrentDate);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Array.Find<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9hy2xwa(v=vs.110).aspx)  returns the element matching the criteria. In you case since it is an array of `Hire` type, it will return element of type `Hire`, which you cannot assign to `DateTime`. You can do:

```
List<DateTime> allDates = hiredetails.Where(hire=> hire.HireDate <= hire.CurrentDate)
                          .Select(r=> r.HireDate)
                          .ToList();
```

You can also return `IEnumerable<DateTime>` and exclude `ToList()` from the above statement.

Not really sure if you need this but instead of keeping the current date inside the object you can have that in your local variable and pass that in your query like:

```
DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
List<DateTime> allDates = hiredetails.Where(hire=> hire.HireDate <= currentDate)
                          .Select(r=> r.HireDate)
                          .ToList();
```

Comment: Looks like I'm a week or so early, but in case I don't run across you again soon: welcome to the 100K club.

Comment: I believe you missed `.Select` as hireDetails are likely of type `Hire[]`.

Comment: Congrats on Nearly hitting 100K. While your code helped me with that problem it also created another error and to be honest i have no idea what it even means...   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Assignment_3.Program.Hire>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.DateTime>'

Comment: @Lammer it means that you should review the solution I provided below :) But @Habib already updated his answer as well to reflect the need to use `.Select` along with the `.Where`.

Comment: My bad, did not seen the update. Anyway thanks both of u

Answer (score 0):

Do not store current date in a structure, use local variable instead, solution would look like:

```
var currentDate = DateTime.Now;
var result = hiredetails.Select(h => h.HireDate).Where(d => d <= currentDate);
```